# Can't retrieve sharedPreference when activity is resumed from history on Samsung Galaxy S 2.2.1

Tags: android

Have a user who just updated to 2.2.1 on his Galaxy S.  Now, when he hits HOME and then relaunches the app, I can see in the logs that the application context is re-initialized and a new process ID is created (verified via log messages in onCreate() in my application instance.)

The odd thing is that when it is relaunched from history, my shared preferences where I store important state are no longer available and all requests to context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Mode.WORLD_PRIVATE).getString() return NULL which ultimately leads to a force-close.

After re-launching the app again, everything works as expected and the sharedPreferences are again available.

I've only noticed this on the Samsung Galaxy S after he upgraded to 2.2.1.

The odd thing I'm curious about is the fact that it appears a new process is launched when returning to the app.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

I've read a little about task re-parenting, etc, from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#proc, but not sure any options would really help here?

Comment: Do you have android:launchMode="singleTask" on your main activity which also has: <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>

Comment: I don't have singleTask -- when I change it to have singleTask, it relaunches the app from the start and doesn't display the last activity.  I'm reading up on tasks, launchmodes, and task affinities now to understand things better.  This seems to be a nice resource: http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/02/17/android-activites-and-tasks-series-an-introduction-to-androids-ui-component-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up modifying my PreferenceActivity subclass to initialize the shared prefs from a database table when the activity starts and to write to the database when a value has changed.  PITA, but all Samsung S issues are now gone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be samsung issue - I've noticed very similar issue with 2.2.1 ROM on Galaxy S

Comment: I've searched around, but can't find a user/developer forum for Samsung Android issues.  Anyone know where we can report these issues, a forum, etc?